# Easiest way to locate a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I encountered my first Segmentation Fault today (newbie programmer). After reading up on what a segmentation fault is (Thanks for all of the helpful info on this site, as well as Wikipedia's lengthy explanation), I'm trying to determine the easiest way to go about finding where my fault is occuring. It's written in C and the error is occuring on a *NIX based system (I'm not sure which one to be honest... 99% sure it's Linux). I can't exactly post my code as I have numerous files that I'm compiling that are all quite lengthy. I was just hoping for some best practices you have all observed. Thanks for your help.

P.s. I'm thinking the error is coming from dereferencing a NULL pointer or using an uninitialized pointer. However, I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: First segfault eh? I can assure you it won't be the last. ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a debugger, such as `gdb` or if this is not applicable a `strace` tool to get a better insight into where the segfault occurs.

If you use `gcc`, make sure you compile with `-g` switch to include debugging information. Then, `gdb` will show you the exact location in a source code where it segfaults.

For example, if we have this obvious segfaulty program:

**new.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int *i = 0x478734;
        printf("%d", *i);
}
```

We compile it with `gcc -g new.c -o new` and then run the `gdb` session with `gdb new`:

We issue the `run` command in the interactive session and the else is clear:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/Tibor/so/new
[New Thread 9596.0x16a0]
[New Thread 9596.0x1de4]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040118a in main () at new.c:6
6               printf("%d", *i);
(gdb)
```

As DasMoeh and netcoder have pointed out, when segfault has occured, you can use the [`backtrace`](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html) command in the interactive session to print a call stack. This can aid in further pinpointing the location of a segfault.

Comment: Thank you very much. This should help this process not become so mindnumbing :) I'll be accepting your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: Sadly you didn't mention `backtrace`, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use `valgrind`. It will pinpoint to the location where the invalid access occours (and other problems which didn't cause crash but were still invalid). Of course the real problem could be somewhere else in the code (eg: invalid pointer), so the next step is to check the source, and if still confused, use a debugger.

Comment: +1 valgrind is *very* useful, however not much without debug flags.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Tibors answer.

On larger programs or if you use additional libraries it may also be useful look at the backtrace with gdb: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_42.html

Answer (score 1):

I reopen this posts for people passing here since I've just corrected a segfault I've made using gcc.

You should consider using the flag **-fsanitize=address** which can sometimes highlight your segfault with high precision.